# Apple goes outside box, and a # is being written at the far right. Why?

Tags: c#

I really don't know how to phrase my title, help me out.

---

I am having an issue with a game I am making. The game's objective is to eat an apple that appears on the map for points. When you eat it, another apple appears in a random location inside the little box.

[image: Apple goes out of bounds]

As you see the apple goes out of the bounds. But it doesn't always happen on the first time I get to it. Also, there is a # at the very far right for some reason.

Here is the code:

The drawing happens in the `Draw()` method, so you should look at that first.

```cs
using System;

public class MainClass
{
    public const int WIDTH = 20, HEIGHT = 20;
    public static int Points, X, Y, FruitX, FruitY;
    public static bool GameOver = false;
    public static string Direction;
    public static Random Rand = new Random(); 

    public static void Start()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        GameOver = false;
        Direction = "Stop";
        X = WIDTH/2;
        Y = HEIGHT/2;
        FruitX = Rand.Next(100)%WIDTH/2;
        FruitY = Rand.Next(100)%HEIGHT/2;
    }

    public static void Draw()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("# ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(j == 0 ? "# " : " ");

                if (j == WIDTH - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("# ");
                }
                if (i == Y && j == X)
                {
                    Console.Write("O");
                } 
                else if (i == FruitY && j == FruitX)
                {
                    Console.Write("");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH + 1; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("# ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"\nPoints: {Points}");
    }

    public static void InputHandler()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo UserInput = Console.ReadKey();

        switch (UserInput.KeyChar)
        {
            case 'w':
            Direction = "Up";
            break;

            case 'a':
            Direction = "Left";
            break;

            case 's':
            Direction = "Down";
            break;

            case 'd':
            Direction = "Right";
            break;

            case 'x':
            GameOver = true;
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void GameHandler()
    {
        switch (Direction)
        {
            case "Up":
            Y--;
            break;

            case "Down":
            Y++;
            break;

            case "Left":
            X--;
            break;

            case "Right":
            X++;
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }

        GameOver = X > WIDTH || X < 0 || Y < 0 || Y > HEIGHT;

        if (X == FruitX && Y == FruitY)
        {
            Points += 10;
            FruitX = Rand.Next(100)%WIDTH/2;
            FruitY = Rand.Next(100)%HEIGHT/2;
        }


    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start();

        while (!GameOver)
        {
            Draw();
            InputHandler();
            GameHandler();

        }
        Console.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of variables in your code that we don't have the declarations of.  What do `FruitX`, `FruitY`, `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` contain?

Comment: @Amy sure I updated my question

Comment: Try adding a `Console.WriteLine()` after the 1st `for` loop?

Comment: Please don't make us tease out your code line by line. You are still missing important information. How are `FruitY` and `FruitX` being set? (i.e. How are you using your `Rand`instance?)

Comment: @AndySavage this is the only way it's being set
`FruitX = Rand.Next(100)%WIDTH/2;`

`FruitY = Rand.Next(100)%HEIGHT/2;`. I tried using smaller numbers than 20 but it still goes past the box

Comment: @incapaz I started a fiddle with your code. The extra # at the far right is fixed. Please add additional code so we can see the full example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cCEWjZ

Comment: @jcruz done adding it all

Comment: @incapaz I can't reproduce the apple going out of bounds. I've update the fiddle, if you keep running it the apple is always within bounds.

Comment: I use visual studio but in the screenshot i used repl.it as im not at home right now. If you use an ide like vs or repl it it will work

Comment: After the first `for` loop where you draw the top horizontal row of # signs, the cursor is _still_ out there on the end of that line.  Then, inside your nested loop, you write a space in the default `else` branch until `j == WIDTH`.  These spaces are written at the end of the first line.  When `j == WIDTH` you then write a # sign and the cursor is still on the end of that line.  You need to make sure the cursor is in the correct place when you draw each symbol.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway so I write a newline after?